# bootstrap 4.0 / css for input:readonly

Tags: css

How can I change the look of the read-only font colour.

I found a way to change the background- colour

```
input:-moz-read-only  /* For Firefox */
background-color: yellow;
input:read-only 
background-color: yellow;
```

but the same code don't work for colour.

Also to change opacity has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's not a right syntax. You have to put:

```css
input:-moz-read-only {
  /* For Firefox */
  background-color: yellow;
}

input:read-only {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

And, that needs to be inserted in any of the CSS files you are using or inside the `<style>` tags in HTML.

A snippet here for you:

```css
input:-moz-read-only {
  /* For Firefox */
  background-color: yellow;
}

input:read-only {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" readonly value="Can't change." />
```

**Preview**

[image: previw]

Comment: sorry, I know how to write css files. But it has no effect to my page. specialy in bootsrap 4.0 I need to change the pre set css of the frame work of the color of readonly.

Comment: @R.HeinrichK.Fassbender Can you produce a snippet, I'll try to fix it?